# How to install Ubuntu and eliminate Windows?

Tags: installation, 12.10, windows, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10, but when I turn on the PC, I can choose between Win 7 or Ubuntu. How do I install Ubuntu substituting completely Windows?.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? If you install it booting from DVD or USB it should ask you how you want to install it (e.g. keeping windows or not). If you install from Windows using Wubi you don't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

You chose to install it side by side. Try reinstalling Ubuntu and click the "Erase Windows and Install Ubuntu" option. This is a super simple thing that should not have been overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you already installed ubuntu, I advise you to use the ubuntu partition manager to format the windows partition. But if you don't mind reinstalling ubuntu and go through the recovery of files, then do the installation process (boot from a ubuntu live cd or usb) again, this time choose "use all the disk space" (or something similar) when asked what to do at the installation.